# Show that $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Show that $$f(x)=x^{1/3}$$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

$$\text{LHD at} \ x=0$$  $$= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0-h)-f(h)}{0-h-0}$$$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-h^{1/3}}{-h}=\lim_{h\to 0}-h^{-2/3}$$
and similarly $$\text{RHD at} \ x=0=\lim_{h\to 0}h^{-2/3}$$
If I directly substitute $h=0$ both will be $0$ or should I take $0$ to the denominator. 
How do I solve this?

and I have another doubt:

> How is $$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{-2/x}=0???$$

Thankyou

Comment: If you directly substitute $h=0$ (whatever "directly substitute" means) both will be $+\infty$.

Comment: $$\text{is it} \ \frac{1}{0^{2/3}}?$$ If yes then both will not exist and the function is not differentiable. Is my observation correct? and By directly substitute I meant getting $0^{-2/3}$

Comment: @Did: If that is correct please post it as an answer. It might be helpful to other users

Comment: @chndn : your assertion in the gray box is false.  Who told you this?  $\lim_{x\to 0^+} e^{-2/x} =0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^-} e^{-2/x} = +\infty$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume $f'(0)$ exists. Consider $g(x)=(f(x))^3=x$.Then by the chain rule $g'(0)=3(f(0))^2f'(0)$. Since $g'(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$, we find $1=0\cdot f'(0)$, which is absurd.

---

For your second question (which you might prefereably have posted separately):
We have
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}e^{-2/x}=0$$
because $-2/x\to-\infty$, but 
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{-2/x}=+\infty$$
because now $-2/x\to+\infty$.
So $\lim_{x\to0}e^{-2/x}$ does not exist.

Comment: and can u answer my 2nd question?

Comment: So $e^\infty=0?$ and how is $g'(0) = 0$?

Answer (score 3):

To show that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, you need to show that $\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$ does not converge as $h \to 0$ which you did (you get $\pm \infty$ as potential limits).

Comment: Does it mean that LHD and RHD do not exist?

Comment: What do you mean by LHD and RHD exactly?

Comment: Left Hand Derivative and Right...